# GAE Datastore - query filter on nested class

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Java & GAE datastore to store, manage and retrieve some data for my application.

Basically I have two classes: Customer and Store. The idea is that one customer can have more than one store associated, and many customers can exist.

The structure of a customer is something like this:

```
<Customer>
   <id>id1</id>
       <Stores>
           <Store>
               <storeId>100</storeId>
               <city>Venice</city>
           </Store>
           <Store>
                <storeId>200</storeId>
                <city>Milan</city>
           </Store>
           <Store>
                <storeId>300</storeId>
                <city>Venice</city>
           </Store>
       </Stores>
 </Customer>
```

As I said before, there can be MANY customers:

```
<Customers>
    <Customer>
       ...
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
       ...
    </Customer>
</Customers>
```

I need to build a filter to get only a portion of these customers, passing to a query a "CITY" parameter:
For example, if I want to show Customers that has at least one Store located in Venice, I would do something like ( just to give you the idea)

```
GET Customer WHERE Customer.Store.City = 'Venice'
```

What I'd like to get is every Customer that has a Store located in a particular city.. but also, the Customer Object needs to have those stores! like this:

```
<Customer>
    <id>id1</id>
       <Stores>
           <Store>
               <storeId>100</storeId>
               <city>Venice</city>
           </Store>
           <Store>
               <storeId>300</storeId>
               <city>Venice</city>
           </Store>
        </Stores>
</Customer>
<Customer>
    <id>id2</id>
       <Stores>
           <Store>
               <storeId>700</storeId>
               <city>Venice</city>
           </Store>
        </Stores>
</Customer>
```

I can get those stores correctly, but I need to find a way to connect every store to his ancestor customer..

```
String city = 'something';
Query query = mgr.newQuery(Store.class, "city == '"+city+"' ");
List<Store> oggetti = (List<Store>) query.execute();
```

Any idea on how to do this?

I hope I was clear enough.. thanks in advance, best regards

---

Additional info:

class Customer:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
@Cacheable("false")
@FetchGroup(name="customerstores", members={@Persistent(name="storeList")})
public class Customer {

    @PrimaryKey
@Persistent
private String id= "";

    @Persistent
    @Unowned
private List<Store> storeList;

    //getters and setters here
    ....
}
```

Class Store:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
@Cacheable("false")
public class Store {

    @PrimaryKey
@Persistent
private String storeUniqueKey = "";

    @Persistent
    private String city = "";

    //getters and setters here
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if following code could fit your requirement.

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(Customer.class);
query.declareVariables("Customer store");
query.setFilter(
    "this.stores.contains(store) && store.city == \"SomeCity\"");
Collection result = (Collection)query.execute();
```

Comment: thanks spiritwalker, It's almost working.. I can successfully retrieve the customers, but inside the result Object there are not the stores.. I've also updated my question with customer and store class code. Thanks for your help

Comment: actually, I was missing a line of code, to display the stores. My fault! your solution works, thanks!